# Assign jQuery function when nav-tabs are clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using bootstraps nav-tab in my page. Is it possible to assign a jQuery function to the nav-tabs? So what I need is to be able assign `getDate();` if any o these nav tabs are been clicked.

example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
function getDate(){
  //do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To call `getDate` on every tab click you can do this:

```
$('.nav-tabs').on('click', 'a', function() {
    getDate();
});
```

or if this is the only code you want to execute on click it can be shortened to

```
$('.nav-tabs').on('click', 'a', getDate);
```

Comment: Did not work? I added an `alert()` inside `getDate()`. Does not work. These nav-tabs are wrapped inside `<div id="nav_tabs_main"></div>`

Comment: Oops, sorry. I mistyped: `click` goes first, then `a`.

Comment: nope! that did not work either. I even tried an `alert("clicked")` after `$('.nav-tabs').on('click', 'a', function() {` . Doers not work.

Comment: Try this: `$(function() { $('.nav-tabs').on('click', 'a', function() {...}); });`

Comment: Well then it should work. http://jsfiddle.net/vmvyLmsx/ Can you make a fiddle when it doesn't work?

Comment: oops! my bad. I'd done something really silly. It works perfectly. thanks for your time. 1+

Comment: No problem, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Just bind the click event and pass function referene. Try this..

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').click(getDate)
```